# Keras Attention Layer Issue with LSTM regression

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, attention-model

I am using a `keras` `LSTM` for a regression model. I would like to utilize an Attention-Mechanism on the raw inputs as explained very well in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335082154_AT-LSTM_An_Attention-based_LSTM_Model_for_Financial_Time_Series_Prediction).

The paper describes how to build a custom Attention layer that gives weights to the raw inputs before feeding to the `LSTM`. I would like to utilise the new keras `Attention` layer. After looking around on how to implement this I came up with the below model:

```
sequence_input = layers.Input(shape=(time_steps, features), dtype='float32')
lstm, state_h, state_c = layers.LSTM(units=50, 
                                     dropout=0.1,
                                     activation='tanh',
                                     return_state=True,
                                     kernel_regularizer=1e-6,
                                     recurrent_regularizer=1e-4,
                                     bias_regularizer=1e-6,
                                     return_sequences=True)(sequence_input)
context_vector, attention_weights = layers.Attention()([lstm, state_h])
output = Dense(units=1)(context_vector)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=sequence_input, outputs=output)
```

The above model is giving the below `TypeError` when compiling the `Attention` layer:

```
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension.
```

This is because the first dimension of `sequence_input`, `lstm` and `state_h` is `None`. I am new to the `Attention` layer and I am pretty sure I am missing something. The [keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/attention/#attention-layer)  only has an example where an `Embedding` layer follows the `Input` layer which is not something I need for a forecasting regression model where each sample is a `float`.

**PS:** There might be other issues after the Attention layer. I have not yet been able to get past this issue first. Not claiming this implementation is correct.

### Update

One issue is that I am passing a 2D tensor to Attention(). The hidden state has shape (None, 50). Shouldn't the LSTM have a hidden state for each feature, i.e. (None, 50, 10)?,  Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946995/how-to-build-a-attention-model-with-keras), It seems like the hidden state should be passed as the value. So I am not sure why the dimensionality is not correct.

Comment: The Keras attention layer accepts 3D data, you are passing 3D and 2D... pay attention to also what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @MarcoCerliani The returned hidden state of the lstm is (None, 50). Shouldn't there be a hidden state for each feature?

Comment: I suggest you this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775631/10375049

Comment: @MarcoCerliani the answer says "value is the hidden state [batch_dim, features] where we add a temporal dimension for matrix operation [batch_dim, 1, features]. however hidden state is returning [batch_dim, units] instead.

Comment: yes, for this reason, we add a temporal dimension in order to have it in 3D

Comment: @MarcoCerliani my point is hidden state is [batch_dim, units] not [batch_dim, features] as assumed in the answer.

Comment: it's simply a terminology mismatch, units and features can be interpreted as the same thing, the focal point is another

Comment: The error "Cannot iterate over a tensor with unknown first dimension." persists. Probably because the size of the first dimension of 'lstm' and 'state_h' is 'None'

Comment: pay attention... Attention layer return one element not 2.... is context_vector = Attention()([...]) not context_vector, attention_weights = Attention()([...])

Comment: about your edited question: attention calculates a dot product, that's why the last dimension is reduced.