# How can I add tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention in my model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, attention-model

I am working on a machine language translation problem. The Model I am using is:

```
    Model = Sequential([
          Embedding(english_vocab_size, 256, input_length=english_max_len, mask_zero=True),
          LSTM(256, activation='relu'),
          RepeatVector(german_max_len),
          LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=True),
          Dense(german_vocab_size, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

Here,`english_vocab_size` and `english_max_len` are the total number of english words in the english vocabulory and number of words in each english sentence respectively. And the same is with `german_vocab_size` and `german_max_len`.

Now, how can I add `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention` layer in this Model?

Edit - I tried a lot to find good tutorials of implementing `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention` layer on an nlp task, but couldn't find any. So, I think if someone can explain how can I  put the `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention` layer in this model, the person would be the first person to give a very clear explanation on how to use `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention` as it would be then very clear implementation  on how to use the `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention` layer !

Comment: Does this help? - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AdditiveAttention

Comment: possible explanation and solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62949137/6827830

Comment: I have no technical background in this area, so I cannot help you myself. So please allow me to refer you to these descriptions of what you can do to improve your question and make it more answerable. [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers I know it is generic, but please take it as the constructive advice it is meant to be. Good luck with your bounty. It is a good way to get attention.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you from the previous link

[How to build a attention model with keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946995/how-to-build-a-attention-model-with-keras)

```
context_vector, attention_weights = Attention(32)(lstm, state_h)
```

or

This is how to use Luong-style attention:

```
attention = tf.keras.layers.Attention()([query, value])
```

And Bahdanau-style attention :

```
attention = tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention()([query, value])
```

The adapted version:

```
weights = tf.keras.layers.Attention()([lstm, state_h])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should know is that you must know the input for your attention layer `tf.keras.layers.AdditiveAttention()`. And then you must know how to use the output from your attention layer. If these two points are clear, I don't think it is difficult for you to build your model with an attention layer.